# Execute an SSH command with the Apache2 www-data user

Tags: command-line, ssh, php

I'm working on a virtual machine project where I use two servers, let's call them server A and server B, both with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.

Server A runs web server Apache2 with a website where users can order Virtual Private Servers. Once the order process of the user is complete, the user clicks on a button which instantiates the following command with the PHP exec() function.

```
ssh -p 22 john@serverB.com fallocate -l 2048M /home/john/images/guest.img 2>&1
```

This should create an image on server B where ultimately the user's Virtual Private server is created. Running previous command with user john works perfectly, but because the command is run via PHP, www-data is the user executing it.

As expected I get the following errors back:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "Permission denied, please try again."
  [1]=>
  string(36) "Permission denied, please try again."
  [2]=>
  string(39) "Permission denied (publickey,password)."
}
```

I know about the security risks of giving this user sudo rights to become a different user and execute the command as "john". So my question therefor is: is there any other way to do this operation without modifying www-data's permissions? I believe that SSH is the only way to create something on a remote server, or am I wrong?

I'm not going to run the website on server B to create these images locally, this is not what I want.

Is this script answered by this user worth trying? https://superuser.com/a/547577/514523

Comment: Just another question about that permission error - are you sure you are logged into the server? Can you see in the log that user john has logged in? How do you authenticate?

Comment: Well, since the command is executed by www-data, it's that user that tries to ssh to server B. I get those permission denied errors because www-data does not have a password. If I log in with user john and execute that command, everything works fine.

Comment: So www-data cannot login to server B? But the login script uses 'john', not 'www-data'.

Comment: I decided to create a cronjob that lets user 'john' ssh to server B. I haven't worked it out yet, but it will work for sure.

Comment: You could give www-data on server B a password to login, but I would not recommend it, with security in mind. So using 'john' is better.

Comment: Yup, I wouldn't do that either.

Comment: I know some ssh but the rest is over my head.. nevertheless, i'll suggest this.. if it's the case that your ssh command works fine but just not when run from php then you should show the php.. and then maybe it's more of a php related q. And you could try simplifying your command to `echo asdf>~/a.a` to see if that works

Answer (score 0):

You should make www-data owner of /home/john/images, or add it to the john group while giving it proper write rights, or chmod that folder to 777.

---

Try this:

```
chmod 777 /home/john/images/
```

Then you give anyone rights to that folder, including www-data.

That may be too much, so if this works you can limit rights. You could add www-data to the john group:

```
groups www-data
groups john
usermod -aG john www-data
```

First you see to which groups www-data and john belong. Then you add www-data to the john-group.

Now you have to limit the rights to that folder:

```
chmod 775 /home/john/images/
ls -al /home/john/images/
```

Now the user 'john' and all members of the group 'john' have write privileges.

Comment: This does not do anything because I still need to SSH to server B.

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Btw: it's much easier if you don't use 'user' as a username. Use 'john' or whatever, so it's clear it's a person's name. The word 'user' has two meanings here, and that's confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want to use my own name there, but I guess it doesn't matter that much hehe. I'll try what you suggest.

Comment: I added www-data to the 'john' group, and changed rights of the /home/john/images/ folder but it does not have any effect. I think the problems lies that www-data may not ssh to server B just as 'john' is able to.

Comment: I think we're having an XY problem here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Try to explain what you want to do with that image. Explain it in the question. Why do you need to do this, why using ssh? Maybe ssh is not the way to go.

Comment: I've updated my question which explains more what I want to do with that image.